# Variable isn't initialized when trying to use methods

Tags: java, variables, methods, initializing

```
calculateArea(Length, Height, Width);
     double area;
     calculateCost(area);
}

public static double calculateArea(int l, int h, int w) {
    //Variables
    double area;
    //Length = l;
    // Height = h;
    //Width = w;
    //Find the area
    area = l * h * w;

    //returns area outside the method
    return area; 
}

public static void calculateCost(double ar)

PaintCalculator.java:39: error: variable area might not have been initialized
      calculateCost(area);
                    ^
1 error
```

I can't figure out why it isn't initialized when I returned the value for area in the `calculateArea` method. I've tried declaring and initializing the double area; above `calculateCost`, but I'm stumped as to why area inside the `calculateCost` is set to double the area.

Comment: Please correct your code.

Comment: @HalilİbrahimOymacı I think that's why they're asking the question.

Comment: @PC Luddite This code has missing brackets. I want to corret this situation and correct indentation.

Comment: From what I can guess from what you have posted, you have two "public static" methods. "double area;" is given in the first, but has no relation to anything in the second.

Comment: On your second line, your `area` variable does not have any value attributed hence Java complains about that. Initialize it or attribute it the return value of `calculateArea(Length, Height, Width);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must assign your variable `area` to your function `calculateArea`:

```
  double area = calculateArea(Length, Height, Width);
  calculateCost(area);
```

Answer (score 0):

the value for area is currently null, set it equal to something or use the other method you have shown to calculate the area